# cURL and SimpleBrowser

Tags: php, curl

I have a script that lets me log into xbox live using simplebrowser. How ever the browser detector on xbox live takes me to a blank page after log in that has an empty form that needs to be submitted. But the form doesn't show on my browser so simplybrowser can't find it to submitted. The creator of the script says I need to use cURL, how can I use curls with simplebrower?

Here's the script.

```
require_once('simpletest/browser.php');

$browser = new SimpleBrowser();
$browser->get('http://live.xbox.com/en-US/profile/profile.aspx?pp=0&GamerTag=');
$browser->setField('Email Adress', 'blah@blah.com');
$browser->setField('Password', 'blah');
$browser->clickSubmitByName('SI');
$browser->submitFormById('fmHF');
return $browser->getContent();
```

Comment: Small tip: if you indent code by 4 spaces, it'll get formatted as a block of <pre>-like text. Would make it much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with just sending form using cURL.
View form source and get **form action** url from `<form action="(here)" ...>` and put it in `$link` variable.
Every form field put in string with *field name* and *value*, like this:

```
$postdata = 'EmailAdress=blah@blah.com&Password=blah';
```

the rest of the script will look like:

```
$curl_obj = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_URL,$link);
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1); 
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookiefile");
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookiefile");
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_obj, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
$response = curl_exec($curl_obj);
```

in the `$response` variable will be returned page content.
or just `return curl_exec($curl_obj);`

Comment: try `file_put_content('return.htm',$response);` just to see what it returns.